# Lexical Error Appears while running xcode

Tags: android, iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to run the app in phonegap using xcode for creating the cardova based application and I could not run it, while I am trying to do so, I am getting this error

**lexical or preprocessor issue expected end of line in processor expression**

hi am new to iphone development i am creating app for iphone using phonegap i just selected cordova based application in template for your new project in xcode and then provide the name for the app and then i choose a folder for my app and then i clicked run button.After that my app build is failed with 32 errors assertsmacro.h

Comment: Paste code that is causing that.

Comment: @ grzegorz krukowski #if DEBUG_ASSERT_PRODUCTION_CODE this is the line which causes error

Comment: #ifdef is proper macro for objective C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a very frustrating error. Eventually I found this setting that fixed it.

1. Go to the Build Settings tab for the Project.
2. Under `Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language - Modules`, change `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` to No.

Lots of info about this at http://stoneofarc.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/introduction-to-objective-c-modules/.